# ASP.NET MVC 4, Code First, MySQL

Tags: mysql, asp.net-mvc-4

Unable to retrieve metadata for 'MvcStore.Models.Customer'. Using the same DbCompiledModel to create contexts against different types of database servers is not supported. Instead, create a separate DbCompiledModel for each type of server being used.

Web.config

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="StoreContext" connectionString="Server=127.0.0.1; port=3306; Database=webmvcstore; Uid=root; Pwd=root;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

Context

```
public class StoreContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Customer> Customers { get; set; }
    }
```

Entity

```
public class Customer
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

DLLs

> Mysql.Data, Mysql.Data.Entity, Mysql.Data.Web

.NET Framework 4.5

Visual Studio 2012

I don't know how to fix this. In VS 2010 with MVC 3 everything works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hei man!!

try to change the provider name to providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Comment: it didn't solves the problem in my case. any hint?